# how to remove large objects in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

should I call lo_unlink ?
A delete didn't remove the object from pg_largeobject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to explicitly call lo_unlink(). I assume you just DELETEd the row that held a reference to it, and that will not remove the actual large object.

If you only ever reference it from the same place, you can always create a trigger to do it automatically for you.

Answer (score 15):

You can also clean up large objects from the command-line using

```
$ vacuumlo -U username databasename
```

Comment: This is great. It can be found in package postgres-contrib on Fedora distributions.

Comment: Sadly AWS RDS is not currently allowing it. But find [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/174663/48347) my workaround for that disallowance.

Comment: Actually vacuumlo can connect to a remote database instance